# Nested For loops in MATLAB - Possibility for optimization?

Tags: matlab, nested-loops

Given `n` by `n` orthogonal matrix `Q` and diagonal matrix `D` such that all diagonal elements of `D` are nonnegative, I want to compute diagonal matrix `T` such that diagonal elements were equal to `t(i)=1/(q(i,1)*q(i,1)*d(1)+q(i,2)*q(i,2)*d(2)+...+q(i,n)*q(i,n)*d(n))`.

I am using Matlab:

```
Q=[0.7477 0.0742 0.6599; -0.5632 0.5973 0.5710; -0.3518 -0.7986 0.4883];
D=diag([0 0.7106 2.2967]);
n=length(Q);
L=Q*sqrt(D);
t = zeros(n,1);
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        t(i) = t(i) + sum(L(i,j)^2);
    end
end
T = sqrt(inv(diag(t)));
```

As you can see I have used nested for loops. Is it possible to avoid using loops at all?

Comment: `L(i,j)^2` seems to be a single number. Why are you using `sum` here? I'm trying to understand what operation you want to assign to each `t(i)` for removing the loops, but a sum applied to a single number doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        t(i) = t(i) + sum(L(i,j)^2);
    end
end
```

What are you trying to do? `sum` sums more than one number, but `L(i,j)^2` is one number.

Instead, we can use your code to sum over `j` indices and remove the loop.

```
for i=1:n
    t(i) = t(i) + sum(L(i,:).^2);
end
```

But, you defined `t = zeros(n,1);`, i.e. `t` has nothing in it, so your for loop is equivalent to:

```
for i=1:n
    t(i) = sum(L(i,:)^2);
end
```

Knowing this, we can do it in one go:

```
t = sum(L.^2,2)
```